# Do the Tits-Kantor-Koecher construction extend to non unital Jordan algebras?

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-superalgebras, jordan-algebras

I have an infinite dimensional Jordan algebra which is not-unital. I would like to study a Lie algebra related to it (if it exists). Natural choice would be to look at the KKT construction, but looking at the [original](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373242) article of Koecher it seems that its construction is only valid for unital Jordan algebras. While the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantor%E2%80%93Koecher%E2%80%93Tits_construction), which in this case is just a stub, does not mention any condition.

Do you know if the condition of the Jordan algebra being unital is an essential one or if it can be removed in some way? Is there any other canonical construction that could give in this setting a Lie algebra from a Jordan algebra?